# Assign values based on the number of occurrences in dependence of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with keyword ranking data for multiple cities, like in the example below:

```
| Location | Keyword               | Position | Domain       |
|----------|-----------------------|----------|--------------|
| London   | Python developer jobs | 1        | Domain-A.com |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 2        | Domain-A.com |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 3        | Domain-B.com |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 4        | Domain-A.com |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 5        | Domain-B.com |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 6        | Domain-C.com |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 7        | Domain-C.com |
| London   | Data scientist jobs   | 1        | Domain-A.com |
| London   | Data scientist jobs   | 2        | Domain-B.com |
| London   | Data scientist jobs   | 3        | Domain-C.com |
| New York | Python developer jobs | 1        | Domain-B.com |
| New York | Python developer jobs | 2        | Domain-A.com |
| New York | Python developer jobs | 3        | Domain-B.com |
| New York | Python developer jobs | 4        | Domain-A.com |
| New York | Data scientist jobs   | 1        | Domain-A.com |
| New York | Data scientist jobs   | 2        | Domain-A.com |
| New York | Data scientist jobs   | 3        | Domain-A.com |
| New York | Data scientist jobs   | 4        | Domain-A.com |
| …        | …                     | …        | …            |
```

I have a hard time coming up with a function that creates a new column and assigns a decreasing  value  based on the number of occurrences of the domain in dependence of the Location and Keyword.

So The first occurrence of any Domain for Keyword X in Location Y receives the Value 10, the Second occurrence of the domain in the same keyword and location group  receives the value 5 and all further occurrences within this group recieve the value 1.

The Final result should look like the following:

`````
| Location | Keyword               | Position | Domain       | Value |
|----------|-----------------------|----------|--------------|-------|
| London   | Python developer jobs | 1        | Domain-A.com | 10    |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 2        | Domain-A.com | 5     |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 3        | Domain-B.com | 10    |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 4        | Domain-A.com | 1     |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 5        | Domain-B.com | 5     |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 6        | Domain-C.com | 10    |
| London   | Python developer jobs | 7        | Domain-C.com | 5     |
| London   | Data scientist jobs   | 1        | Domain-A.com | 10    |
| London   | Data scientist jobs   | 2        | Domain-B.com | 10    |
| London   | Data scientist jobs   | 3        | Domain-C.com | 10    |
| New York | Python developer jobs | 1        | Domain-B.com | 10    |
| New York | Python developer jobs | 2        | Domain-A.com | 10    |
| New York | Python developer jobs | 3        | Domain-B.com | 5     |
| New York | Python developer jobs | 4        | Domain-A.com | 5     |
| New York | Data scientist jobs   | 1        | Domain-A.com | 10    |
| New York | Data scientist jobs   | 2        | Domain-A.com | 5     |
| New York | Data scientist jobs   | 3        | Domain-A.com | 1     |
| New York | Data scientist jobs   | 4        | Domain-A.com | 1     |
| …        | …                     | …        | …            | …     |

````

Thanks for you support!
`````

Comment: please put your data in text and not in image

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `groupby`:

```
grp = df.groupby(['Location', 'Keyword', 'Domain']).cumcount()

setter = {0: 10, 1:5}

df['cumcount'] = grp.apply(lambda x: setter.setdefault(x,1))
df
```

Output:

```
    Location    Keyword Position    Domain  cumcount
0   London  Python developer jobs   1   Domain-A.com    10
1   London  Python developer jobs   2   Domain-A.com    5
2   London  Python developer jobs   3   Domain-B.com    10
3   London  Python developer jobs   4   Domain-A.com    1
4   London  Python developer jobs   5   Domain-B.com    5
5   London  Python developer jobs   6   Domain-C.com    10
6   London  Python developer jobs   7   Domain-C.com    5
7   London  Data scientist jobs 1   Domain-A.com    10
8   London  Data scientist jobs 2   Domain-B.com    10
9   London  Data scientist jobs 3   Domain-C.com    10
10  New York    Python developer jobs   1   Domain-B.com    10
11  New York    Python developer jobs   2   Domain-A.com    10
12  New York    Python developer jobs   3   Domain-B.com    5
13  New York    Python developer jobs   4   Domain-A.com    5
14  New York    Data scientist jobs 1   Domain-A.com    10
15  New York    Data scientist jobs 2   Domain-A.com    5
16  New York    Data scientist jobs 3   Domain-A.com    1
17  New York    Data scientist jobs 4   Domain-A.com    1
```

Comment: Brilliant, so simple and elegant, thank you very much! :)